# Interesting problem in logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I know this place isn't for math problems/homework, and believe me I've been trying for a long time to solve this problem (45 mins to 1 hour) and besides I think many would find this useful or at least interesting, so here it is :

If $\log_6 15 = a$ and $\log_{12} 18 = b$ what is $\log_{25}24$? (The answer must be in terms of a and b)

Comment: I think this has been asked before (deja vu). I can't seem to find it after searching though...

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $\log 24^{25}$ ?  That would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @DanielV 100% positive

Comment: @Ashkan Please edit your question to reflect your answer to surb's comment.  If you need help with the latex, right click on his equation and click "Show Math As" -> "Tex Commands".

Comment: @DanielV The question seems fine to me, what part requires changing?

Comment: @Ashkan well you responded to a comment that you meant $\log 6^{15}$ rather than $\log_6 15$, saying that the former is what you intended, but it has since been deleted, so ignore me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the identity

$$\log_x y=\frac{\ln y}{\ln x}$$

Then your problem says that

$$\frac{\ln 3+\ln 5}{\ln 2+\ln 3}=a$$

$$\frac{\ln 2+2\ln 3}{2\ln 2+\ln 3}=b$$

and you need to find

$$\frac{3\ln2+\ln 3}{2\ln 5}$$

in terms of $a$ and $b$.

---

We can simplify things a bit if we divide the numerators and denominators of all the fractions by $\ln 5$ and let $x=\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5},\ y=\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 5}$. We then know that

$$\frac{y+1}{x+y}=a$$
$$\frac{x+2y}{2x+y}=b$$

and we want to find

$$\frac{3x+y}{2}$$

We now have two simultaneous equations with two variables. Simplifying the equations we get the linear equations

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  ax      & + & (a-1)y & = & 1 \\
  (2b-1)x & + & (b-2)y & = & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

Using Cramer's rule, we get

$$x=\frac{2-b}{ab+a-2b+1}$$
$$y=\frac{2b-1}{ab+a-2b+1}$$

Substituting these into our formula, we get

> $$\log_{25}24=\frac{5-b}{2ab+2a-4b+2}$$

This can be checked with a calculator, defining $a$ and $b$ as in your problem and calculating both my final expression and $\log_{25}24$. Those figures agree and are both $0.987317934353$.

Comment: Thank you mate, I can proceed but I think it's better if you complete your answer

Comment: To solve a fraction with 3 variables, two equations are enough.

Comment: Actually Rory I can't proceed and I'm frustrated as hell, could you please complete your answer, the curiosity is killing me

Comment: This seems like an odd question. Surely you could write the result in terms of a and b with just: $$\frac{3\ln2+\ln 3}{2\ln 5}-a-b+a+b$$ How much trickery do you have to do before you can say that it's in terms of a and b?

Comment: @Cruncher: A reasonable interpretation would be that the problem asks for the answer as a _rational expression_ in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Please check the last denominator, I suspect $-4ab$ term should read $-4b$.

Comment: @CiaPan: Yes, my correction and your comment were saved at just about exactly the same time.

Comment: @Ashkan: I have "completed" my answer, though of course I left out some of the steps. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: @Rory I will do that, Thank you very much